# Selenium StaleElementException after refilling in form after submission

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, forms, selenium

I have a form that I am trying to automate filling in for one of my Selenium scripts. There is a form that has about 4 text fields of which the HTML looks like this

```
<input class="class" id="id" name="name" value="" autocomplete="off" wtx-context="stuff" type="text">
```

Then after filling those forms, there is an input submit button with the following HTML code

```
<input id="id2" class="class2" value="Add Material" wtx-context="morestuff" type="submit">
```

I have used the following Java code and am successful in getting the forms to be filled in and submitted, but once they are submitted, I assume what is happening is they are refreshed on the DOM and then I get a StaleElement exception thrown at me. I've kind of hacked my way around it by going to the homepage and navigating my way back to the webpage with the form, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution if anyone knows one. Below is my Java code.

```
Page.WriteToField(Page.Input_number(), "111111111");
Page.WriteToField(Page.Input_number2(), "222222222");
Page.WriteToField(Page.Input_date(), format.format(cal.getTime()));
Page.WriteToField(Page.Input_number3(), "3333");
Page.SubmitIngredient();
```

The WriteToField() function looks this

```
public void WriteToField(WebElement field, String text) {
    field.click();
    field.clear();
    field.sendKeys(text);
}
```

And I access all of the WebElements from my page classes using the following format

```
public WebElement Input_number() {
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("form1")));
}
```

Comment: When do you actually get your `StaleElement` exception? And how is `Input_Number` constructed? If the page is reloading, you'll probably want `SubmitIngredient()` to return a new `PageObject` if you're using the **PO Model**. If not, it looks like you'll still want to recreate that object once you submit the form, because the page is being reloaded(probably).

Comment: You likely need to add some sort of wait after `Page.SubmitIngredient();` to make sure the page has completed (re)loading before allowing the script to move on.

Comment: @mrfreester The StaleElement exception comes once I try to write new inputs into the forms after submitting. What do you mean by return a new PageObject?

Comment: @Qyler essentially it's going stale because the page reloads, so you have to re-find all the elements. So after you submit you need to reconstruct your object. So if you `return new WhateverPage()` for your `SubmitIngredient()` method you could do `WhateverPage whateverPage = Page.SubmitIngredient(); whateverPage.WriteToField(blahblah);` This would work because you're creating a new instance finding all your fields fresh for the next round.

Comment: @Qyler I think I could provide an answer, but I would have to see how `Page` gets initialized, and possibly the full example of writing the first time successfully, and then trying the 2nd time unsuccessfully to see the code flow between those two attempts.. Any chance you can provide your code that shows that?

Comment: @mrfreester I was able to solve the problem actually by doing what you said actually and having my methods return a `new Page` object so thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try to check the presence of an element before actually checking whether it is clickable or not?

```
public WebElement Input_number() {
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("form1")));
      return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("form1")));
}
```

**Update-** 
the reason I have asked to add Expected condition for the presence of an element is that it does perform find element operation again. [Please refer implementation of `presenceOfElementLocated` method below] So I'm hoping one would get element in return. [But I may be wrong]

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ExpectedConditions.findElement(locator, driver);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "presence of element located by: " + locator;
        }
    };
}
```

Apart from that if you check implementation of `elementToBeClickable` method [below code block], it does not perform find operation and if element is not visible or enabled it throws `StaleElementReferenceException`  exception.

```
 public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement visibleElement = (WebElement)ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element).apply(driver);

            try {
                return visibleElement != null && visibleElement.isEnabled()?visibleElement:null;
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException var4) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "element to be clickable: " + element;
        }
    };
}
```

So checking presence of element before checking whether element is visible make sense to me [As I said earlier, I may be wrong]

Comment: It can't be clickable if it's not present. The first wait isn't necessary.